# Why is my render time unusually high for a simple object?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I recently got Boxcutter and HardOps and so have been doing a lot of hard surface work with booleans. I have made several models of roughly similar complexity, lit them in the same way, and rendered them with identical settings:

- Cycles
- 200 passes
- 6 bounces
- Denoising and Glare nodes in Compositing
- 1920x1080 resolution

This usually results in a render time of about 2.5 minutes on my 10th gen i7 6 core processor. I do have a GPU but it's not the greatest - the CPU is faster.

Yesterday I made another fairly simple model - just a crate with boolean doodads - applied the same render settings, and went to render it - but Blender is predicting a render time of 5.5 *hours*.

What can I look at to see what might be causing this sudden massive jump? I can only think that I've enabled some setting or done something with the modelling itself, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: render time doesn't always have to do with object it can just be the 200 samples you have that make it take a while

Comment: Have you ticked the ‘square samples’ checkbox by mistake? That would result in 200x200 samples instead of just 200 - which would be close to the projection you’re seeing.

Comment: @RichSedman nope, that's turned off. I reduced the resolution by 50% and made the tile size 16x16 which brought it down to around 20 minutes. Still seems odd to me though.

Comment: I've gone back to an older save and it seems maybe my lighting was just too complex. But i've done exactly the same lighting (HardOps has a kind of built in auto-lighting tool) with other projects with no issue. Odd.

Comment: You don't mention how many poligons you are dealing with or what modifiers you are using. There is no information on your question to help us help you.